X25519Kyber768Draft00 Key Exchange still in use, even after GPO/Registry to disable
I am trying to find out if there is another place to disable the Post-Quantum key exchange options other than what has been published Chrome/MS for browsers. The X25519Kyber768Draft00 Key Exchange option is still being offered by clients as an option, even with the GPO/Registry fix.  The "odd" thing is that it only happens when embedded Microsoft Apps are connecting to web-servers (Outlook, Outlook addins, Teams etc).  If/when I connect to the same sites via Chrome/Edge, that key exchange option is not "offered" by the client.
